# Filed ITR-1 without clearing due tax - What are my options now?

Tags: income-tax, india

So I filed my [ITR-1 Form](http://www.incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/home)

I had some 5k tax due that I had to pay but I thought of paying it after submitting ITR. As it turns out, I do not see any option in the above mentioned site to pay the due amount and I've already submitted the ITR-1 form.

I heard about something called Challan 280 but not sure how I would link it to the the ITR that I filed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit the [NSDL site](https://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/Pages/tax-services/pay-tax-online.aspx). Select form 280. In form 280, Select 0021 income tax. Select 300 self assessment tax. Pay the taxes via netbanking. You will get the BSR details on confirmation page.

Go to IT returns, file an amendment, enter the BSR details in tax details and submit the form.

Comment: So do I e-verify the original return before filing the amendment (and by amendment I assume you mean "revised return") or skip it?

Comment: @asprin yes, e-verify original return. File a revised return and e-verify